# okhttp OAuth interceptor

Tags: java, multithreading, oauth, okhttp

I try to implement an oAuth interceptor for okhttp and I couldn't get a complete solution for that problem. My current solution looks like this:

```
public abstract class AuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {

  /**
   * We are super lazy and use this lock object, instead of Lock and Condition
   */
  private Object lock = new Object();
  private AtomicBoolean authenticated = new AtomicBoolean(false);

  @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

    final Request request = chain.request();
    Response response = chain.proceed(request);

    if (response.code() != 401 ) {
      return response; // should not intercept, we are done;
    }

    // response code was 401
    authenticated.set(false);

    synchronized (lock) {

      // TODO pause okhttp executore service

      if (!authenticated.get()) {
        if (doAuthentication()) {
          authenticated.set(true);
        } else {
          // authentication failed, so forward original response (401)
          return response;
        }

        // TODO resume okhttp executor service
      }
    }

    // Redo the request, by adding the fresh access token
    return redoRequest(chain);
  }

  /**
   * Gets a fresh auth token from server.
   * Returns true if a new valid auth token was retrieved from server
   */
  protected abstract boolean doAuthentication();

  /**
   * re-execute the request by setting the new (valid) auth token
   */
  protected abstract redoRequest(Chain chain);
}
```

The idea is to only allow one Thread (or you could say one request) that has a 401 response to refresh the auth token by calling `doAuthentication()`. All other Threads should wait in front of the `synchronized` block. Once the Thread who has executed `doAuthentication()` leaves the `synchronized` block `authenticated = true` and therefore the other threads should not invoke `doAuthentication()` again.

But I see one problem: In theory the thread the following scenario with two Threads would be possible:

1. Thread 1 enter `syncronized` block
2. Thread 1 executed `doAuthentication()` and got a new (valid) auth token.
3. Thread 1 set `authenticated = true`
4. Another Thread 2 overrides `authenticated.set(false);` (before the `synchronized` block)
5. Thread 1 leaves synchronized block --> new (valid) auth token
6. Thread 2 enters synchronized block. Since `authenticated` has been overridden it executes `doAuthentication()` again, **which should NOT be done**, because the auth token retrieved a few milliseconds ago be Thread1 should be used.

I think in practice this will not happen quite often. However does anyone of you see a perfect solution for that problem? I also thought about pausing / okhttps `ExecutorService` while getting a new auth token to minimize the risk of struggling upon this scenario.

Comment: in theory you can pause the whole okhttp `ExecutorService` by intercepting every call in a `synchronized block`
so if you persist your authentication state on disk, you can do that unless authenticated

Comment: I thought about that, but it's possible that requests had started before authenticating has started and those requests return with a 401 response after ` authenticated.set(true);` but before  leaving `synchronized`. Therefore the scenario described above is still possible.

Comment: did u get any workaround for this scenario